# Storing simple information in online database in android

Tags: android, database

I am programming android app and I need to store simple data on server. I need to store only users email address, his nickname, and who invited him to the app. Is there some way how to do it, instead of setting my own server?

I was searching for some simple way, like some easy API for sending it to google server, so I wouldn't need to care about security.

Comment: Check out google app engine; the api can handle login without prompting the user for password. You'll automatically get their email when they login because that's their user-identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Parse](https://parse.com/products/core#pricing) for storing data upto 1Gb for free. Also see https://parse.com/products/data. I heard from those who used it, that the API is quite straight forward.